# create a directory for every file and generate “n” copies for each file

Tags: bash, file, directory, copy

while I was looking for a solution for my files, I found something that is perfect, I include the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219991/how-do-i-create-a-directory-for-every-file-in-a-parent-directory/220026#220026?newreg=94b9d49a964a4cd1a14ef2d8f6150bf8

but now, my problem is how can generate 50 copies to the directories generated by each file I was dealing with the following command line

```
ls -p | grep -v / | xargs -t -n1 -i bash -c 'for i in {1..50}; do cp {} "{}_folder/copy${i}_{}" ; done'
```

to get the following

```
-file1.csv---->folder_for_file1---->1copy_file1.csv,2copy_file1.csv,3copy_file1.csv........50copy_file1.csv
-file2.csv---->folder_for_file2---->1copy_file2.csv,2copy_file2.csv,3copy_file2.csv........50copy_file2.csv
-file3.csv---->folder_for_file3---->1copy_file3.csv,2copy_file3.csv,3copy_file3.csv........50copy_file3.csv
...
-file256.csv---->folder_forfile256---->1copy_file256.csv,2copy_file256.csv,3copy_file256.csv........50copy_file256.csv
```

How can I match this with the previous answer??, include the functional code of that answer

```
cd ParentFolder
for x in ./*.csv; do
  mkdir "${x%.*}" && mv "$x" "${x%.*}"

done
```

all the credits to the person who generated this great answer and thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the move for a copy/remove and add a for loop:

```
cd ParentFolder
for x in ./*.csv; do
  mkdir "${x%.*}"
  for (( i=1;i<=50;i++ )); do # Create a loop, looping 50 times
     cp "$x" "${x%.*}/copy$i_$x" # use i in the copy command
     rm -f "$x" # Remove the file after the 50 copies
  done
done
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, but apparently it does not work as expected, but nevertheless I thank you very much for your attention

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Actually I've just spotted and amended. I hadn't put the directory in the destination for the copy command.

Comment: I understand, but I think that when it generates the copies, it deletes all of them, or it doesn't generate them at the beginning, but I don't know if maybe it's my version of bash, I use version 4.3.48

Comment: It shouldn't do. $x is the initial file ${x%.*} the directory and $i the copy number. rm -f $x will remove only the initial file.

Comment: looks more like a file to folder converter, but thanks for your help

Comment: It is making the directory and then copyimg the file $x to the location {x%.*}/copy$i_$x. This is the directory followed by / and then copy, then _ then the filename. Is this not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tests and I can publish the following code that works partially, because it effectively copies each file 50 times within the generated folder, but with the name "copy" to each new file, and also adds the extension .csv, but if someone can provide a solution to solve this would be great, I thank to @Raman Sailopal for his help and comments

code

```
cd pruebas
for x in ./*.csv; do
    mkdir "${x%.*}" 
    for ((i=1;i<=50;i++)); do # Create a loop, looping 50 times
    cp "$x" "${x%.*}/copy_$x_$i.csv" # use i in the copy command
    #rm -f "$x" # Remove the file after the 50 copies
    done
done
```